# Stack's en los UIViewController de iOs

Tags: swift, swift3

Se me están mezclando muchas cosas acerca de la forma en que se navega por los distintos controladores.

1. ¿Cuando yo hago un `func present(UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)`
   , hay una stack en la cual se van agregando mis controladores? Si es así, ¿que diferencia habría con respecto al funcionamiento del `UINavigationController`?
2. ¿Que diferencia hay entre una presentación del tipo modal a una del tipo show?(Se que está en explicado en la página de apple pero me gustaría si alguno me lo puede explicar con sus palabras)
3. ¿Cuando debo preocuparme por tener muchas instancias de los controladores? Es decir, ¿Cuando los controladores se mantienen referenciados(Por ejemplo: en un stack)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Al llamar a la función  `func present(UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)` desde un UIViewController, estas presentando el nuevo controlador de manera modal, no agregándolo a la pila. Esa es la diferencia con respecto a un `UINavigationController`, éste sí agrega los controladores a la pila.
2. Un buen ejemplo de presentación modal son las pantallas para añadir información (a una tabla, un contacto nuevo, evento de calendario, etc). Puedes ver que no hay botón de atrás, suelen aparecer Aceptar/Guardar y cancelar, pues sus acciones suelen limitarse a descartar la vista o guardar la información que contiene.
3. Si diseñas tu UI mediante Storyboards, y no haces ninguna cosa extraña, te diría que nunca. En el momento que navegas hacia atrás en la pila, y si no tienes manualmente una referencia al controlador desapilado, éste se elimina de memoria.

Saludos